# Corrupted inputStream

Tags: java

It errors at the last line in the client code, with the code. java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 36353137.  I haven't done anything to the stream before this point, so I am unsure what could be causing the problem with the ObjectInputStream.

The server class works properly, and follows the behavior I set for it, it is only the client class that is erroring.

I thought the problem at first might be because the stream wasn't being flushed, but flushing it did not fix the issue.

Apart from that, since this error is happening so early in the code, I am at a loss as to what to add to fix it.

Client class -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class tcpClient {

    int nonce;
    Socket requestSocket;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String message;
    tcpClient(){}
    void run()
    {
        try{

            requestSocket = new Socket("localhost", 3223);
            System.out.println("Connected to localhost in port 3223");

            out = new ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(requestSocket.getInputStream());
```

Server Class -

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TCPMasterServer
  implements ActionListener
{
  ServerSocket server;
  Socket client;
  Random random;
  Calendar rightNow;
  Timer timer;
  String ipaddress;
  PrintWriter out;
  BufferedReader ir;

  public TCPMasterServer()
  {
    this.random = new Random();
    this.rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    try
    {
      this.server = new ServerSocket(3223);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void listenForConnection()
  {
    try
    {
      this.client = this.server.accept();
      this.ipaddress = this.client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
      System.out.println(this.rightNow.getTime() + ": Connected from: " + this.ipaddress);

      this.out = new PrintWriter(this.client.getOutputStream(), true);
      this.ir = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.client.getInputStream()));

      communicateWithClient();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      listenForConnection();
    }
  }

  private void communicateWithClient()
  {
    this.timer = new Timer(2000, this);
    this.timer.setRepeats(false);
    this.timer.start();
    try
    {
      int nonce = this.random.nextInt(1000000);
      this.out.println(nonce);
      System.out.println(this.rightNow.getTime() + ": Send nonce: " + nonce);


      String input = this.ir.readLine();
      Scanner in = new Scanner(input);
      int nonceResponse = in.nextInt();

      System.out.print(this.rightNow.getTime() + ": Received number: " + nonceResponse);
      if (nonceResponse == nonce + 1)
      {
        System.out.println("... OK");


        this.out.println("SEND_NAME");
        System.out.println(this.rightNow.getTime() + ": Request name");

        input = this.ir.readLine();
        System.out.println(this.rightNow.getTime() + ": Received name: " + input);


        this.out.println(input + " ACK");
        System.out.println(this.rightNow.getTime() + ": ACK sent");
      }
      this.client.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      System.out.println(this.rightNow.getTime() + ": Error happened. Giving up");
    }
    this.timer.stop();
    System.out.println();
    listenForConnection();
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    try
    {
      System.out.println("Timer fired.");
      this.client.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    TCPMasterServer server = new TCPMasterServer();
    server.listenForConnection();
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the actual exception and stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using object streams at the server, but readers and writers at the client. That won't work. If you want to read objects you must write objects.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it now.  Thanks.